# Como permitir apenas letras e números numa caixa de texto

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu estou a fazer um formulário e a primeira solução que vi foi criar um teclado com botões com apenas letras números o botão de apagar e o de espaço mas agora o que eu queria mesmo era uma caixa que permitisse apenas números e letra pois torna-se muito chato escrever com o teclado virtual como posso fazer isso numa pagina web?

Alguma ideia? ou o teclado virtual com botões é a melhor ideia?

```
<form>
<input type="text" required="required" name="text" pattern="[a-z\s]+$" />
</form>
```

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas comentar isso na pergunta tira o foco do seu problema, e passa pro downvote. Se a intenção é que alguém te ajude, evite comentar votos dentro da pergunta.

Comment: Mas a realidade é que não vou saber o que esta errado apenas com votos

Comment: Que tal adicionar o que você já tentou fazer? Melhoraria bastante a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma expressão regular para limitar o seu input a aceitar apenas os caracteres que você deseja:

Js:

```
$('#text').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9._\b]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b0aLrpkn/1/